# Partiti : solve this new type of puzzle

Tags: grid-deduction

These are puzzles similar to Kakuro, which is the creation of a friend of mine whom I met last year:

[image: Partiti_1]

> Rules: Place one or more digits from **1 to 9** in arbitrary order in each empty cell, such that a number in the top left corner of each cell is **the sum of digits** entered in that cell. (A cell with no number in the corner still needs one or more digits, but you aren't told its sum.) Same digits cannot be placed in a single cell or in cells that touch, even diagonally.

---

[Partiti: puzzles and partition,  Thinh Van Duc Lai](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04495.pdf)

---

> Puzzle source: http://logicmastersindia.com/lmitests/dl.asp?attachmentid=710

Comment: Hey, I know this puzzle from last week's contest :D -> http://logicmastersindia.com/PR/201802/

Comment: Yes, that is from IB. By the way, do you also participate in the PR?

Comment: Yep, but I must admit I have less experience in it (I just started to participate last month I guess haha xD)

Comment: @athin, nice :) I was injured the past week, couldn't give my level best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this works:

> [image]

How I solved it:

> The top right gives some easy answers (1, 2, from there the three 4s). Then I simply checked the possibilities for adjacent cells, which were all solvable on their own when done in the right order.

Comment: That's correct but also fill the centre :)

Comment: @ABcDexter Ah, I presumed since it was empty I shouldn't fill anything in. Does it mean I can fill in anything (non-zero) instead?

Comment: Well, if you look at the eight adjacent cells then there is only one value which goes in there, which is 9.

Comment: @ABcDexter Yeah I noticed that. My question was intended more in the direction of "Can I have any sum I want, as long as the adjacent cell rules are satisfied?" to which the answer, if I understand correctly, is yes.

Comment: Btw, nice puzzle! Haven't seen it before (though I have done kakuro's)

Comment: @Lolgast You even have to place a number since the first rule states that each cell has to have at least one digit in it.

Comment: @wl Well, yeah, but it also says the sum of digits should be equal to the number in the top left corner. The absence of one for the center cell left me a bit confused.

Comment: @Lolgast I read "a number in the corner is..." as: "If there is a number in the corner, it has to equal the sum"